# One-to-many recursive relationship in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to have an `Organization` which have relation to parent one. Something like this:

```
type Organization struct {

    gorm.Model

    Parent *Organization `gorm:"ForeignKey:ParentId"`
    Name string `gorm:"size:30"`
    Description string `gorm:"size:100"`
}
```

I want to have `ParentId` field which will be referenced to `id` field in the same table. But as I see there is no field and relation.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Try making `ForeignKey` lower case, as in the docs http://doc.gorm.io/associations.html#has-one

Comment: I have already tried it. The same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved it like this, but I am not sure that it is a correct way:

```
type Organization struct {

    gorm.Model

    Parent *Organization
    ParentId int `gorm:"TYPE:integer REFERENCES organizations"`
    Name string `gorm:"size:30"`
    Description string `gorm:"size:100"`
}
```