# How do I rewrite advanced query with gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a table with models. Model can be parent to another model (1 to many)

```
type Model struct {
    ID                             uuid.UUID
    Name                           string
    ParentModel                    Model
    CaseID                         uuid.UUID
}
```

What I am trying to do here is to get all relatives models by their link (same case_id or parent). And I found how to do it with simple query:

```
with recursive model(id, name, case_version, parent_model_id, case_id) as (
  select models.* from models  
  where models.case_id = '1'
union all 
  select models.* from models 
  inner join model on model.id = models.parent_model_id
)
select * from model
```

I am not really experienced with gorm, so I am stuck at "with recursive model() as (...)"
How to do it with qorm?
My progress so far:

```
    subquery := db.Raw("? UNION ALL ?",
        db.Select("models.id, models.name, models.case_version, models.parent_model_id, models.case_id").
            Where("models.case_id = ?", caseID).
            Model(&model),
        db.Select("models.id, models.name, models.case_version, models.parent_model_id, models.case_id").
            Joins("inner join model on model.id = models.parent_model_id").
            Model(&model),
    ).Scan(&model)
```

Will be grateful for any help

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619377/one-to-many-recursive-relationship-in-gorm) looks very much like what you are looking for.